# unable to remove SQL syntax in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am updating table when i run this query it give an  error:

```
 client.query('UPDATE Campaign SET ( Name, StartDate ) VALUES ( "' +req.body.Name+ '" , "' +req.body.StartDate+ '" ) WHERE idCampaign = ' +id , function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("err found" + err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result[0])
    }

});

 ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( Name, StartDate ) VALUES ( "" , "" ) WHERE idCampaign = 89126b2d-c906-11e2-9cf'
```

I dont know where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the error description, `idCampaign` is a string and not a number so you need to use quotes. Try with this

```
 ... WHERE idCampaign = '" + id + "'"
```

**EDIT**

I totally missed that your `UPDATE` statement was all wrong, I just paid attention to the error message. @RedBaron is correct but you still have to use the quotes on `id`. Try with this

```
"UPDATE Campaign SET Name='" + req.body.Name + "', StartDate = '" + req.body.StartDate+ "' WHERE idCampaign = '" + id + "'"
```

Comment: i am writing this query client.query( 'UPDATE Campaign SET Name=' + req.body.Name + ', StartDate= ' +req.body.StartDate+ ' WHERE idCampaign = "' + id + '"', function(err, result) {

        if(err) {
            console.log("err found" + err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result[0])
        }

    });

Answer (score 1):

That is not how an update statement is used in MySQL. Look at the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Broadly the query should be like

```
'UPDATE Campaign SET Name=' + req.body.Name +', StartDate ='+req.body.StartDate+ ' WHERE idCampaign = ' + id
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE idCampaign = 351adc56-c906-11e2-9cfa-74867a028324' at line 1
@RedBaron

Comment: @ana I think you should print out the query as a string, before you pass it to `client.query`. It will help you to debug it better. As Claudio has pointed out in his answer, you are probably missing out quotes (Especially since date is supposed to be quoted)